# How to make Product Version property match executable's version number automatically

Tags: installshield

I have an InstallShield project with 2 executable's. How do I change the product version property in General Information of InstallShield to match one of my executable's version number. I'm using auto builds.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

In your auto build script, you can set the ProductVersion property.
For example :

```
<InstallShieldPropertyOverrides Include="$(MSIProductCode)">
  <Property>ProductCode</Property>
</InstallShieldPropertyOverrides>
```

Comment: Does this go in the pre-build step?

Comment: @ChopperCharles: I am pretty sure it does not. Did you figure this out? I just started reading through possible solutions.