# Getting the Version of my C# app?

Tags: c#, windows, version

I am working on desktop application. I have create a setup.

> Ex. My Application. Version is 1.0.0.

I want to get the current version of my desktop application which is `1.0.0`. I have tried by using `Application.ProductVersion` but it provides the version of my controls. (I am using `DevExpress Control`15.2.7, so it provides the current version as `15.2.7`).

How can I get the current version of the installed application? I want to compare it to the installed version to provide a "New Version Available" functionality for my product.

Comment: Depends how your application is implemented. Basically, question as it stands, can't be answered.

Comment: @Leri It is setup created by InstallShield Express Edition 2015.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The info you are looking for is in **AssemblyInfo.cs**.

To access the info written in there at runtime you can use the `System.Reflection.Assembly`.

Use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` to get the assembly (**that this line of code is in**) or use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` to get the assembly your project started with (**most likely this is your app**).

**In multi-project solutions this is something to keep in mind!**

```
string version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
// returns 1.0.0.0
```

Corresponding **AssemblyInfo.cs**:

[image: AssemblyInfo.cs]

Corresponding **EXE-properties**:

[image: EXE properties]

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15018835/4610605) may be important when working with InstallShield (see comments) !**

Comment: Please check your AssemblyInfo.cs. What is written in there ?

Comment: if this doesn't help anything try working with `GetEntryAssembly` rather then `GetExecutingAssembly`

Comment: I didn't set Assembly Info. I am working 3rd party InstallShield for creating setup. I have set version and all in it but didn't set in Assembly. I thought InstallShield will manage. Anyways, I have changed Assembly info. It is working fine now. Let me know if I still understand wrong.

Comment: *"I thought InstallShield will manage"* - that's wrong assumption, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15018932/1997232).

Answer (score 14):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly executingAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var fieVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(executingAssembly .Location);
var version = fieVersionInfo.FileVersion;
```

Comment: It returns "15.2.7.0" which is my DevExpress Component version.

Comment: what is executingAssembly .Location giving you? path of your application exe or something else?

Comment: Here is all parameter. (1) Assembly Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe.     (2) File Version/Product Version: 15.2.7.0

Answer (score 7):

Another approach, which is basically the same as the accepted answer, is:

```
Version appVersion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
versionLabel.Text = "v" + appVersion.Major + "." + appVersion.Minor + "." + appVersion.Build + ".";
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the version of a specific assembly:

```
private const string AssemblyName = "MyAssembly"; // Name of your assembly

public Version GetVersion()
{
    // Get all the assemblies currently loaded in the application domain.
    Assembly[] assemblies = Thread.GetDomain().GetAssemblies();

    for (int i = 0; i < assemblies.Length; i++)
    {
        if (string.Compare(assemblies[i].GetName().Name, AssemblyName) == 0)
        {
            return assemblies[i].GetName().Version;
        }
    }

    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version; // return current version assembly or return null;
}
```

Comment: I was originally using `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` which worked while debugging under Visual Studio and while running standalone, but when the XAML designer loaded it would return the current Visual Studio version (or the version of some component). This solution works in all three situations :D

Answer (score 2):

```
this.Text = this.Text + " " + Application.ProductVersion;
```

Comment: There are **5 existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **one hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

If youe are using Windows Form applicaion, you can using just `ProductVersion`.

```
// Set form text. This is showing upper the form titel bar
this.Text = "Application name" + ProductVersion;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread, but I wanted to show what I did in regards to this and there are some caveats to any method you use above, and this one.

```
    this.Text = "My Awesome App";

    //Get Version
    if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        Version ver = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
        this.Text += string.Format(" v{0}.{1}", ver.Major, ver.Revision, Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name);
    }
    else
    {
        var ver = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
        this.Text += string.Format(" v{0}.{1}", ver.Major, ver.Revision, Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name);
    }
```

Caveats are as follows;

1. You can publish it as a click-once app or standalone and you will get the version
2. You won't see it during testing, you will only see it after you have published it and ran it from the published location.  For the longest time I was looking for it to appear during testing, but alas it only shows after publishing.
3. Here I am only using Major and Revision.  I want to see "My Awesome Appv1.3" .  You can add to this if you want by using Major/Minor/Build/Revision.